# inserting script in mysql forbidden?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a MySQL database with a text field (utf8_general_ci) which I would like to fill with html code. I am using phpMyAdmin 4.2.6 to change this field. I have the impression that including scripts is prohibited (code 403: Forbidden). I tried using the insert-button, the SQL button and the inline editor. All give the same result.

I am inserting the following code: `<html><script></script></html>`, which is not working, while `<html>script/script</html>` is working perfectly. The text field is long enough, I can even make it much larger, as long as there is no `<script>` tag.

Can someone tell if this is a phpMyAdmin or a MySQL problem, or is this a setting somewhere?

Comment: MySQL won't care nor affect your HTTP status codes, so it's something on the web server, either in phpMyAdmin or above it.

Comment: show us your php code

Comment: Can you show the relevant code

Comment: I see no problem  with `script` value: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b2c34/2

Comment: You are using an outdated phpMyAdmin version. Try the latest stable version on http://demo.phpmyadmin.net

Answer (score 0):

This is a phpMyAdmin problem, since this works perfectly fine when using php for inserting this text. Two solutions:

1. use php to insert the values
2. use the 'import' function in phpMyAdmin.